# How to have auto expanding text views all contained within a scrollable container in XCode/Swift/IOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, storyboard

I have a storyboard view which consists of a textview which will display a variable amount of text which is a question. Below that I need to display 4 separate blocks of text - each is a possible answer for the question. They need to be able to react to being pressed and need to expand according to the answer they display.

Currently I have the question in a text view with the answers all being buttons. My question is what the best way of having all my text - question and each answer display within a scrollable view?

i.e. when the user scrolls the entire set of options move rather than just the text in the question or the text within one of the answer options.

Should I convert my answers from buttons to text views as well? If so what should I encapsulate them all in?

Answer (score 0):

I would try selecting all the elements -- the textview and the four buttons --then go to the Editor menu and choose Embed in, then scroll view.

Editor > Embed in > Scroll view.

This will allow all your elements to scroll together as you desire.